# Change input value after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to change a `input` value when `ajax` result is success. Here's my approach but it's not working.
The result of `alert` is **80000**

the html input

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="used" 
     class="form-control used" style="width: 80px;">
```

ajax

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/get_leave_hours',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    success : function(data)
    {
        result = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(result[0].total_leave_consume);
        $(".used").val(result[0].total_leave_consume);
    }
});
```

result of the log

```
{
   payroll_leave_temp_hours: "80.00", 
   total_leave_consume: "80000", 
   remaining_leave: "-79920.00"
}
```

Comment: are there any other elements that uses "used" class?

Comment: @tanaydin only 1 sir.

Comment: give a `console.log(result)` just above the alert, and check whether you are getting the results there

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code?

Comment: What's your HTML?

Comment: '{payroll_leave_temp_hours: "80.00", total_leave_consume: "80000", remaining_leave: "-79920.00"}` result of the log.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney but i have the `used` as the class too sir.

Comment: It seems to be a selector issue. Try to change for `$(input[name="used"])` or give it a id. And retest it.

Comment: @nethkennnnn Apologies, missed that

Comment: just assign a new value `result[0].total_leave_consume = $new_value` ... isn't it ??

Comment: @Striped i just add an id and it worked. How can i mark your answer as a correct answer?

Comment: @nethkennnnn Just upvote the comment. That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared class attribute two times in HTML.

Change your HTML from this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="used" class="form-control used" style="width: 80px;">
```

To this:

```
<input type="text" name="used" class="form-control used" style="width: 80px;">
```

removed first one in above code